# Вместо 404 выдает 200. Как это исправить?

Tags: php, apache

Есть страница с 404 кодом, в .htacess прописан путь к ней, но при ввода адреса 
`www.site.ru/afagasgas` выдается код 200, остается на главной без появления 404 ошибки. Как это исправить?

P.S: Что интересного, когда пишу:

`www.site.ru/бред asdasdas` - выдается код 200

`www.site.ru/бред/бред asdasdas`  - появляется уже 404 (то есть после еще одного слэша уже нормально)

.htacess:

```
#php_value display_errors 1
#php_value error_reporting 2047
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

#400 -  Bad Request
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?component=doc&section=default&value=err400

#404 - Not Found
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?component=doc&section=default&value=err404

#Bad Gateway
ErrorDocument 502 "Sorry, Technical work on server"

DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: Выложите содержимое `.htaccess`. И ещё вопрос: вы пишете в с помощью чего-то (CMS, фреймворк) или на чистом PHP?

Comment: @bet88, вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос, добавив туда содержимое .htaccess

Comment: добавил, странный формат отображения сообщений, для меня)

Comment: @bet88 для форматирования кода можно нажимать кнопку {} в меню текстового редактора

Comment: Тут скорее надо на ваш фреймворк смотреть, на роуты хотя бы.